# Private Docker registry for dependencies in Helm chart

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, docker-registry

I have a Helm chart that uses Nginx chart as a dependency. Is it possible to specify different repo for pulling the image?

My dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  - name: nginx-ingress
    version: "3.15.2"
    repository: "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
    condition: master.ingress.create_controller
    tags:
      - ingressController
```

What I want to achieve is to make k8s pull image from private Docker registry instead of Docker Hub.
I've checked Helm docs, but couldn't find a corresponding parameter. I understand that I can download the chart and change the value inside, but this is my plan B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible only if the chart has an option to do it.

If you look at [the chart's `values.yaml` file](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml) you can see that it has settings:

```yaml
controller:
  image:
    repository: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller
```

And, correspondingly in [the Deployment template](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml#L70-L72):

```yaml
{{- with .Values.controller.image }}
image: "{{.repository}}:{{ .tag }}{{- if (.digest) -}} @{{.digest}} {{- end -}}"
{{- end }}
```

So when you deploy the chart, you can add to your deploy-time settings

```
nginx-ingress:
  controller:
    image:
      repository: docker-mirror.example.com/k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller
```

You can also default this in the parent chart.

Different charts handle this in different ways.  The [Bitnami charts](https://github.com/bitnami/charts), for example, let you separately specify the registry and image names, and support a `global: { imageRegistry: ... }` option.  (Which is just used via string concatenation, so if you have a path prefix in your local registry mirror, you can include both parts there.)

Comment: Thank you for a very consistent reply. It worked!